# Can I take the case of constant temperature in the given equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

I need guidance if i can do this or is there any error in doing this? Consider the equation,
$dP=\frac{\beta}{k}dT-\frac{1}{kV}dV$
$\beta$=Volume expansivity
$k$=isothermal compressibility
In heat and thermodyanmics by zemansky, the case of constant volume is taken, and integrated between two temperature $T_i$ and $T_f$ where $\beta$ and $k$ are taken as constants.
The final equation for this case would be,
$P_f-P_i=\frac{\beta}{k}(T_f-T_i)$
What if I consider constant temperature?
I get the final equation as,
$P_f-P_i=-\frac{1}{k}ln(V_f/V_i)$
I am new to thermodynamics so am i missing any detail or making a blunder while doing this?If not why wasn't this case considered in the book?

Comment: Sure, that's fine.  This assumes a nearly incompressible liquid or solid so that k is essentially constant over the pressure range considered.

Comment: Oh....is the case too trivial to mention in the book?

Comment: I really don't know.  What authors put in a book is up to their discretion.